# Output parameter in dynamic components

Tags: angular

When we want the Parent component listens for child event we use the
@output parameter and subscribing on the parent markup:

```
<my-tag (onMyEvent)="onMyEvent($event)"></my-tag>
```

how do I do it with ComponentResolver?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not supported.
- use a shared service with components that are dynamically added using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` or
- use the `componentRef` it returns to wire inputs and outputs imperatively.

```ts
this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
  this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
  this.cmpRef.instance.someOutput.subscribe(...)
  this.cmpRef.instance.someInput = this.someInputValue;
});
```

Comment: Thanks again. I used this solution: Parent and children communicate via a service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service